# Asp.Net MVC Disable unobtrusive auto validation on page load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I have an html5 placeholders on my textboxes, Name, email, phone.
In order to get it work on ie9 and less I have the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if (!Modernizr.input.placeholder) {
    $('[placeholder]').focus(function () {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
            input.val('');
            input.removeClass('placeholder');
        }
    }).blur(function () {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
            input.addClass('placeholder');
            **input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));**
        }
    }).blur().parents('form').submit(function () {
        $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function () {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                input.val('');
            }
        })
    });
}
```

});

The problem is when page is loaded the unobtrusive validation somehow fires by default and checks the textbox values, and of course in shows error labels because of the values:
input.val(input.attr('placeholder')); are not validated. (it shows email text in email field)

I don't understand why the validation fires on page load and not when I submit a form by button.

Comment: Are you declared that field out of a form?!

Comment: All fields are inside form

Comment: If I add setinterval for 1 sec, on blur event, validation will not fire, but it is not a nice solution.